# how to push a comment in an embedded document in mongodb with java driver

Tags: arrays, mongodb, comments, push, mongo-java-driver

I have the below document:

```
enter code here
```

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c49b52a5b24ba2a979a964"),

```
"FirstName" : "satvik",
"LastName" : "ponakala",
"Major" : "Information Assurance",
"RoomPost" : [
    {
        "postId" : 1,
        "title" : "I have a room to share at Garden Square",
        "comments" : [
            {
                "comment1" : " i want to join",
                "author" : "ashish"
            },
            {
                "comment2" : " already booked",
                "author" : "puneeth"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "postId" : 2,
        "title" : "I have a room to share at Ansley Falls",
        "comments" : [
            {
                "comment1" : " How many can stay",
                "author" : "sandeep"
            },
            {
                "comment2" : "can i come there next sunday??",
                "author" : "sandeep"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

How to add a new comment {
        "comment3":"push comment from java",
        "author":"Java"
        } in the comments section under the post ID : 1 from java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you meed to match postId 1 and then push a new comment to "comments" , something like this :

```
db.[your collection name].update({"RoomPost" :{$elemMatch :{"postId" : 1}}}, {$push : {"RoomPost.$.comments": {"comment3" :"some comment"}}})
```

writing it with the java driver is easy, the 'update' section is something like that :

```
BasicDBObject  update = new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject("RoomPost.$.comments",new BasicDBObject("comment3" ,"some comment" ) ))
```

Hope it helps.